# Complex quotes in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to format quotes the old-fashioned way. — Is there any way to go from this input:

```
<p>He argued that <q>the King by his proclamation or other ways cannot change any part of the common law, or statute law, or the customs of the realm</q> and concluded that…</p>
```

to this output (as displayed on the browser):

```
He argued that “the King by his procla-
“ mation or other ways cannot change any
“ part of the common law, or statute law,
“ or the customs of the realm” and con-
cluded that…
```

In the example above, *hyphenation*, *alignment* and *line length* are set arbitrarily and for illustration purpose. *They aren’t of any concern.*

I would like that, when a line breaks inside the `<q>`, each consequent lines (that are in the `<q>`), when displayed, be preceded by a quotation mark (so as the reader would visually isolate the quote). It is an old-fashioned way of formatting indirect speech.

The best I could come up with so far is an unsatisfactory pseudo-workaround using `<blockquote>` combined with `text-shadow` in CSS:

```css
* {font-family: monospace; line-height: 1.4em; width: 25em; margin: 0;}

blockquote { position: relative; padding-left: 1.2em; text-indent: -1.2em; overflow-y: hidden;}

blockquote::before {content:"“"; position: absolute; top: 1.4em; left: 1.2em; text-shadow: 0 1.4em 0 #000, 0 2.8em 0 #000, 0 4.2em 0 #000;}
```

```html
<p>He argued that <blockquote>“the King by his proclamation or other ways cannot change any part of the common law, or statute law, or the customs of the realm”</blockquote> and concluded that…</p>
```

(Which may vaguely resemble what I wanted (kinda), but ultimately does not work given the block nature of `<blockquote>`; furthermore, when set `inline`, the desired effect of the quotation marks being set to the left is lost.)

**Edit: acknowledging answers.**

Obviously, we are going the JS route. I’ve considered:

- Find *browser-computed* line breaks, and replace each one with `"<br>&ldquo;&nbsp;"`(eventually leading to multiple issues in justified texts—**therefore not ideal**);
- @A-Haworth suggestion of “[a] method to find the line breaks [with] a dummy element, gradually add[ing] the text and spot[ting] when it gets higher.”

But I just don’t know how to do any of these things. Also, there must be a solution I haven’t thought of.

Any idea?

**Last Edit (Feb 16, 2022)**

No one, really?

Answer (score 1):

It probably can't be done in an easy way. I tried to write a small function that might help you.
The solution needs to be finalized, but you can take the basic idea. if you need a dynamic solution, use resize observer, as indicated in the example.

```js
function quote(el, leftPad = 16) {
  const txt = el.textContent.trim().split(" ");
  const ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  const styleList = getComputedStyle(el);
  ctx.font = `${styleList.fontWeight} ${styleList.fontSize} "${styleList.fontFamily}"`;
  const maxWidth = el.clientWidth;
  let paragraph = [];
  let line = "";
  let lineWidth = 0;
  let blockquote = false;
  const symbolMap = new Map();
  let firstLineBreak = false;
  let quoteRowCount = 0;

  const getWordLength = (word) => {
    let wordWidth = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (!symbolMap.has(word[i])) {
        symbolMap.set(word[i], ctx.measureText(word[i]).width);
      }
      wordWidth += symbolMap.get(word[i]);
    }
    return wordWidth;
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    const word = txt[i] + " ";
    const width = getWordLength(word);
    lineWidth += width;
    if (txt[i].search('"') >= 0) blockquote = !blockquote;
    if (lineWidth > maxWidth) {
      paragraph.push(line);
      if (!firstLineBreak && blockquote) {
        line = '<br><span class="newline"></span>';
        firstLineBreak = true;
        quoteRowCount++;
      } else {
        if (blockquote) quoteRowCount++;
        line = "";
      }
      lineWidth = leftPad + width;
    }
    line += word;
  }
  if (line.trim() !== "") paragraph.push(line);
  el.innerHTML = paragraph.join("<wbr>");

  const newLineElement = el.querySelector(".newline");
  if (newLineElement) newLineElement.style.height = `${quoteRowCount}em`;
}

const el = document.querySelector("p");
quote(el);
// or if you need ResizeObserver =>
//new ResizeObserver(() => quote(el)).observe(el);
```

```css
p {
  width: 220px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.newline {
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.newline:before {
  content: '""""""""""""""""""""""""';
}
```

```html
<p>
  He argued that "the King by his proclamation or other ways cannot change any part of the common law, or statute law, or the customs of the realm" and concluded that…
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Oleg! Nice suggestion. I did toy with it a little, although I don't understand the half of it TBH. **1º** Seems somewhat of a resource-intensive method (basically doubling the data), it makes me question its viability for longer texts. **2°** I can't have words breaking haphazardly, it has to be natural breaks at common `&shy;` or `white space`. **3°** The use of white space (after the quotation marks) instead of a padding, albeit unnoticeable in flush left align., will eventually become an issue in a justified context, because of the uneven white spaces.

Comment: @Rotie, I have updated the code. Perhaps this updated example will be a little more interesting. This code is sloppy, but can be the basis for a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question - how much can be done by CSS?

While I think for a totally general answer will  need JS - slowly adding text to the paragraph and looking to see whether the height has changed or not - here's a snippet that does it mainly by CSS using pseudo element. However, as the browser uses the pseudo element to put in the quotation marks itself, these have to be placed in the text if they are still required.

It requires a way of getting the text that is in the paragraph before the q element into the content of the pseudo element also. Here this is done with a data attribute. Space is reserved for the column of double quotes by doing a text-indent on the paragraph.

So, not a totally general solution, but may point to a way of making it general using a bit of JS to do the content setting up initially.

```css
p {
  margin: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -10px;
}

q {
  position: relative;
}

q::before {
  content: attr(data-start) '\a " \a " \a " \a " \a " \a " \a " \a " \a " \a " \a " \a " \a " \a " \a " ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  text-indent: 0;
  white-space: pre;
  padding-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>He argued that <q data-start="He argued that ">"the King by his proclamation or other ways cannot change any part of the common law, or statute law, or the customs of the realm"</q> and concluded that…<br>some more text here for test</p>
```

Comment: Answer is not much. The weakness of the HTML/CSS option lies in the structure itself: elements can either be inline or block; but they can't be both. A solution would be to give the illusion that they're both—then we're back to JS. The most efficient method, as I see it, would be to get a function to detect a computed line break (_i.e._ wrap break), just to add the quotation mark after it; proceed to the next break _et bis repetita_. Of course, we'd add in something like `window.addEventListener('resize', thatFunction)`.

Comment: A method to find the line breaks is to have a dummy element, gradually add the text and spot when it gets higher. Easy with JS, not possible with CSS of course. However using text-indent does give a start.